# Get Authorization info in Custom Validator

Tags: c#, validation, reflection, asp.net-core

i'm writing in asp.net core, in form i have string field `PESEL`(it is some ID number in Poland) and  boolean field `NoPesel`. `Pesel` is validating only when field `NoPesel` is unchecked.

Now i want to add new functionality: If user is SignIn/authorize then turn off validation even if `NoPesel` is unchecked.

And i have no idea how to do this. Should i try to do it by reflecion, or some context? Did someone know how to do this?

```
 public sealed class PeselValidator : ValidationAttribute
 {
    // private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "Nie poprawny numer pesel";

    public string NoPesel { get; set; }


    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (PeselRequired(validationContext.ObjectInstance, NoPesel))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        }


        if ((value == null) || (!ValidatePesel(value.ToString())) )
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(ErrorMessageResourceName);
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());


    }

    private bool PeselRequired(object objectInstance, string NoPesel)
    {
        var propertyInfo = objectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(NoPesel);
        var x = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectInstance, null);
        return (bool)x;
    }

    public static bool ValidatePesel(string szPesel)
    {
        //some logic checking PESEL SUM
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: ValidationAttribute != AuthorizationAttribute. You shouldn't require this type of information. Validation attributes are there to roughly validate the form of data (if they fall in a specific range or fit a specific pattern). Don't try to abuse ValidationAttribute this way. ValidationAttributes are not here to replace your domain logic. For domain logic write your own validators which validates logic beyond range, existence and pattern

Comment: After couple of month i see how newbie i was. For someone: Resolve this by creating two models, for auth and not auth user. Add In controller i used automapper